# A question regarding intensity of electromagnetic waves

Tags: electromagnetic-radiation, astrophysics

Consider a source of electromagnetic radiation in vacuum why does the intensity of electromagnetic radiation reduce with the square of the distance(1/r^2).Since there is no medium there is no loss of energy to the medium.Considering that the source is isotropic and there is no phenomenon of red shifting, can anyone explain this?I have read articles which say that this reduction in intensity is the reason why distant stars appear dim.The level of explanation that would help would be that of a 11th grader.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse-square_law#Light_and_other_electromagnetic_radiation

check out this wp page, and look at the image at the top of the article. The emr as a spherical wavefront will have a specific flux per unit area at any given distance from the source, which follows inverse square. Total power output of source is constant, but the further from source you are, the less flux there will be, as that constant power source will be spread out over a larger area.

Comment: I believe integrating the poynting vector of the far field of a EM source with a surface increasing of a radius ct  will be constant. As energy is conserved but density is reduced

Answer (score 1):

The intensity does not decrease with distance because
the energy is somehow lost to the medium.
Instead, the intensity decreases because the energy spreads
across a larger area when the distance $r$ get larger.
The total energy is actually the same at every distance $r$.

For example: When the distance $r$ doubles, then the area
gets $4$ times larger. And hence the energy per area
(which we call intensity) gets smaller by a factor of $\frac{1}{4}$ there.

[image]
<sub>(image from [Wikipedia - Inverse-square law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse-square_law))</sub>

Answer (score 0):

Intensity is the power per unit area radiated by the source. If the source is spherically symmetric, the area of [the sector of the sphere](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spherical_sector) (a small region at which the radiation has travelled r meters) is

$$A = \Omega\,r^2$$

(where $\Omega$ is the solid angle of that arc) and therefore the intensity at a distance r is

$$I = \frac{P}{\Omega\,r^2}$$

Thus, you can see that the intensity in a region of area $A$, a distance $r$ away from the center of the source, is proportional to $1/r^2$.

If the intensity didn't decrease, then the total energy (the one you can measure in the whole surface of the sphere) would increase!